# Dynamicly change 'fill color' of canvas background svg image using fabric.js

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I have a canvas & using fabric js , on clicking bg_img button one  transparent  svg  image set to canvas as background  image successfully, also i can easily change canvas background color, similarly i want change fill color of this background svg image dynamically.

```
//set SVG image to canvas background
$("#bg_img").click(function() {
    $('.lower-canvas').css("background-image", "url(admin_svg/BB_birds_in_flight.svg)");
    var svg = $('.lower-canvas').find('svg');
});
/////for SVG Image Fill color change
$('#color_shap').change(function() {
    var active_colour = $("#color_shap").val()
    var obj = canvas.getSvgDATA(); //what code should i place here ?
    if(!obj) return;
    obj.setFill(active_colour);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

I have attached screen shot 
This is my design layout.
1[image]

After adding a svg background(having many flaying birds) and i have changed wall color
[image]

Now i want to change the svg fill color of the birds which is initially black in background image?
Anyone let me know how should i do this? answer will be appreciated.

Comment: You might look into SNAP.svg, an open source library which allows for animation/modification of SVG files. Site: http://snapsvg.io

Answer (score 2):

You will need to edit the Edit the admin_svg/BB_birds_in_flight.svg manually so that the birds are in the colours you want. You cannot alter the contents of a background image from the host document.

When used as an image an SVG document is very similar to an ordinary png or jpeg image, it must be all in one file and it can't be manipulated from the outside. This allows hosting sites to upload SVG images and vet them secure in the knowledge that the image won't radically change later.

If you want the colours to change your options are limited to CSS or SMIL animation. Here's a couple of the birds with [SMIL animation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html) - if you put the mouse over one of the birds it will change colour, the other changes colour all the time:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="453.03px" height="472.836px" viewBox="0 0 453.03 472.836" enable-background="new 0 0 453.03 472.836"
     xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M87.984,94.513c0.82,1.46,0.172,2.887-1.164,3.744c-1.421,0.91-2.587,0.431-4.051-0.072
    c-0.674-0.232-1.711-0.772-2.438-0.625c-1.042,0.212-0.678,0.57-1.233,1.269c-0.935,1.17-2.227,1.312-3.746,1.437
    c-1.336,0.107-3.43-0.987-4.604-0.569c-0.926,0.329-0.5,0.813-1.017,1.417c-0.645,0.755-1.024,0.729-2.022,0.859
    c-0.749,0.097-1.64,0.327-2.387,0.329c-0.813,0.001-1.579-0.644-2.299-0.626c-1.511,0.038-1.758,1.945-3.135,2.501
    c-0.939,0.379-1.774-0.021-2.705,0.002c-0.948,0.025-1.389,0.501-2.267,0.708c-1.834,0.435-3.026-0.993-3.218-2.733
    c-1.063,0.744-4.896,4.812-5.61,1.726c-0.734,0.854-2.62,1.085-3.585,0.496c-1.236-0.755-0.802-2.278-0.581-3.509
    c-1.46,0.357-9.383,0.114-5.924-2.45c-1.324,0.217-3.962,0.587-5.209,0.077c-1.852-0.759-0.645-2.461,0.45-3.403
    c-1.24-0.419-3.361-0.411-4.388-1.267c-1.591-1.329,0.586-2.169,1.55-3.019c-1.143-0.3-2.68-0.52-2.697-2.021
    c1.373-0.462,2.821-0.293,4.23-0.822c1.071-0.401,2.134-0.777,3.222-1.079c2.742-0.76,5.067-1.948,7.641-3.161
    c1.217-0.572,2.478-1.093,3.683-1.587c-0.866-0.229-1.215-1.323-1.807-1.437c-0.587-0.113-1.604,0.703-2.431,0.586
    c-1.477-0.209-3.967-1.378-4.219-3.009c-1.846,0.031-2.704,0.462-4.396-0.82c-0.908-0.688-2.61-2.065-2.076-3.348
    c-2.351,0.296-5.791-3.112-6.046-5.326c-2.948,0.842-5.4-3.351-5.91-5.908c-1.004,0.458-2.49-1.13-3.023-1.912
    c-1.078-1.579-0.597-2.212,0.015-3.689c-2.467-0.2-5.402-6.163-2.767-7.659c-1.172-0.18-2.285-2.387-2.62-3.415
    c-0.56-1.717,0.122-2.444,1.469-3.347c-1.387-0.216-3.082-2.939-3.437-4.223c-0.651-2.357,1.116-3.285,3.001-3.967
    c-1.611-0.927-3.746-2.969-4.453-4.715C4.5,26.778,7.816,26.46,10.02,27.035c-1.666-0.67-3.225-3.653-4.081-5.181
    c-0.497-0.889-1.016-2.331,0.146-2.929c0.967-0.499,2.669,0.565,3.644,0.736c1.392,0.244,2.787,0.13,4.178,0.465
    c-2.3-1.848-5.741-4.789-4.775-8.225c0.964-3.433,5.68,1.72,7.266,2.578c1.584,0.857,3.191,1.567,4.704,2.561
    c-2.825-2.965-6.371-5.107-6.314-9.728c0.079-6.399,5.759,0.963,7.4,2.478c1.621,1.495,3.417,2.795,5.058,4.271
    c-2.628-4.239-7.558-8.447-5.277-14.053c1.971-0.211,4.346,3.672,5.579,4.958c2.065,2.156,3.656,4.725,5.427,7.139
    c0.785,1.069,1.701,2.367,2.925,2.842c-1.749-2.986-3.551-6.163-4.153-9.614c-0.144-0.824-0.586-3.085,0.518-3.531
    c1.131-0.457,2.32,1.512,2.791,2.225c2.119,3.212,3.18,6.991,5.406,10.15c1.816,2.579,3.769,4.957,5.353,7.703
    c1.722,2.986,3.542,5.81,5.632,8.557c-0.271-2.031-0.328-4.323,2.122-2.604c1.664,1.168,2.715,2.941,3.393,4.813
    c0.607,1.683,0.859,3.59,2.17,4.905c1.439,1.444,3.671,2.444,5.431,3.438c3.667,2.071,7.476,3.273,11.689,2.444
    c1.896-0.372,3.586-0.839,4.817-2.398c1.394-1.765,2.281-3.686,4.413-4.743c3.608-1.788,10.16-0.13,11.59,3.819
    c1.95-1.132,3.604-1.732,4.692-3.841c1.039-2.013,2.38-4.016,4.639-1.741c2.264-1.687,5.184-2.058,7.484-3.754
    c1.087-0.802,2.128-1.294,3.021-2.3c0.661-0.745,1.148-1.707,1.983-2.291c0.151,1.399-3.497,5.669-2.849,5.166
    c0.648-0.504,19.932-6.459,25.873-14.905c1.23-1.748,2.054-3.679,3.183-5.481c0.286,0.748,0.675,2.016,0.282,2.782
    c0.825-0.706,1.21-1.5,1.338-2.525c0.184,0.016,0.634,0.182,0.81,0.298c1.787,1.198-1.185,5.861-3.115,7.503
    c-0.055,0.052-0.057,0.049-0.008-0.008c0.679-0.538,2.367-2.368,2.976-1.187c0.706,1.371-1.895,3.267-2.702,3.954
    c-2.622,2.234-4.813,3.844-7.887,5.362c-1.469,0.725-2.29,2.128-3.72,2.919c2.12,0.049,4.68-0.223,6.649-0.71
    c1.903-0.47,4.077-1.858,6.091-2.004c-0.503,1.643-3.334,3.179-4.729,4.079c-1.173,0.756-4.695,2.272-4.875,3.642
    c1.871-0.374,4.174-0.06,6.143,0.043c0.292,1.631-3.296,3.008-4.36,3.864c-1.481,1.194-3.405,1.769-4.768,3.164
    c2.587,0.735,3.446,1.63,1.556,3.95c-1.243,1.524-2.484,2.584-4.333,3.28c1.987,2.955-0.029,6.565-3.158,7.324
    c0.427,2.25,0.038,4.796-2.59,4.748c-0.055,2.415-0.623,2.823-2.877,3.459c0.167,0.465,0.033,0.774-0.19,1.246
    c-0.397-0.158-0.611,0.078-0.958,0.047c0.075,2.688-1.458,2.49-3.597,2.877c-0.349,1.479-0.896,1.756-2.078,2.471
    c-1.053,0.637-1.571,1.411-2.369,2.356c-0.763,0.908-1.501,1.903-2.616,2.36c-1.673,0.683-1.723,0.514-2.75,1.96
    c-0.888,1.252-1.739,0.958-2.928,1.641c-1.255,0.723-1.298,1.624-2.92,1.751c-1.518,0.121-1.951,0.46-3.324,0.966
    c-0.795,0.292-2.344,0.852-3.163,0.929c-0.79,0.074-1.344-0.473-2.078-0.567c-0.701-0.092-1.14,0.201-1.806,0.233
    c-1.528,0.072-2.589-0.78-3.223-2.158c-0.55,0.162-0.949,0.615-1.571,0.839c-0.664,0.24-1.007-0.078-1.498,0.005
    c-0.558,0.095-0.992,0.474-1.579,0.564c-0.594,0.092-1.231-0.229-1.897-0.114c0.936,1.37,2.031,2.27,3.313,3.286
    c1.251,0.991,2.118,2.374,3.351,3.349c1.195,0.945,8.085,1.883,5.07,4.587c-1.175,1.053-3.524,0.903-4.996,1.016
    c-0.225,0.198-0.007,0.024,0.119-0.032">
    <animate attributeName="fill" begin="0s" from="#FF0000" to="#FFFFFF" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</path>
<path fill="#020202" d="M32.75,442.628c-3.35-3.172-6.543-7.686-8.207-11.979c-2.085-5.374-3.971-10.904-5.412-16.487
    c-1.339-5.188-2.325-10.639-2.477-16.005c-0.162-5.798,1.792-10.223,5.739-14.402c1.829-1.937,3.762-3.802,5.15-6.097
    c1.313-2.174,1.979-4.586,2.567-7.033h-0.083c-2.1-0.359-3.815-1.056-5.719-1.971c-1.836-0.882-3.815-1.273-5.793-1.696
    c-2.004-0.431-3.877-0.685-5.875-0.07c-1.935,0.596-3.8,1.395-5.741,1.987c-2.285,0.696-4.538,1.433-6.9,1.823
    c3.329-3.627,8.224-5.402,12.573-7.474c0.981-0.469,1.839-1.033,2.534-1.881c0.666-0.811,1.134-1.756,1.976-2.413
    c1.688-1.321,4.514-1.941,6.607-2.2c2.706-0.334,5.238,0.736,7.944,0.887l0.763-0.107c0.26-0.469,0.11-0.883,0.355-1.359
    c2.531-4.93,2.08-10.188-0.101-15.173c-1.062-2.432-2.549-4.857-2.538-7.594c0.008-2.483,1.188-4.817,2.35-6.946
    c2.55-4.678,6.353-8.093,9.741-12.125c3.9-4.64,7.604-9.367,11.671-13.877c3.37-3.736,6.66-7.523,9.707-11.529
    c-0.11,2.445-0.989,4.358-2.077,6.508c-0.514,1.015-1.161,1.991-1.571,3.055c-0.406,1.059-0.403,2.164-0.584,3.268
    c-0.372,2.27-1.527,4.434-2.116,6.673c-0.623,2.369-1.329,4.314-1.437,6.795c-0.093,2.146-0.1,4.888-1.326,6.729
    c-1.389,2.088-3.426,2.635-3.242,5.469c0.13,1.984,0.299,4.062,0.676,6.014c0.445,2.315,1.189,4.271,1.15,6.676
    c-0.077,4.911,1.281,9.625,0.681,14.539c-0.065,0.542-0.621,1.284-0.196,1.625c1.057,0.85,2.096,1.72,2.937,2.791
    c0.916,1.167,1.503,2.562,2.452,3.702c1.926,2.318,5.583,2.692,8.286,3.662c3.051,1.093,6.266,1.676,9.455,2.206
    c3.302,0.549,6.555,1.012,9.801,1.858c3.132,0.818,6.273,1.683,9.51,1.958c0.381,0.031,0.764,0.059,1.145,0.085
    c-0.035,0.068-0.065,0.129-0.088,0.213c-0.753,0.184-1.548-0.155-2.312-0.234c-0.607-0.062-2.059-0.331-2.543-0.073
    c0.53-0.013,1.06,0.321,1.563,0.405c0.53,0.088,1.083,0.075,1.592,0.181c0.915,0.189,2.174,0.315,2.989,0.719
    c-0.933,0.317-1.785-0.205-2.659-0.247c-0.964-0.046-1.85-0.029-2.815-0.123c-1.982-0.191-4.05-0.272-5.997-0.37
    c-3.933-0.195-7.928-0.415-11.891-0.406c-1.964,0.006-4.603-0.251-6.46,0.263c0.399,0.338,0.97,0.517,1.43,0.739
    c-0.375,0.496-1.18,0.071-1.704,0.059c-0.706-0.018-1.355,0.113-2.069,0.077c-1.427-0.07-2.889-0.051-4.294-0.121
    c-2.78-0.142-5.716-0.007-8.494,0.124c-1.341,0.062-3.242-0.204-4.325,0.411l-0.163,0.245c-1.566,4.709-3.674,8.62-

6.002,12.982
    c-1.285,2.408-2.048,4.997-3.642,7.241c-1.232,1.735-2.028,3.638-3.106,5.461c-1.297,2.193-0.963,3.672-0.666,6.104
    c0.28,2.286,0.155,4.715-0.124,6.997c-0.284,2.323-0.421,4.646-0.682,6.967c-0.265,2.359-1.24,4.557-1.477,6.932
    c-0.234,2.356-0.511,4.813-0.479,7.182c0.03,2.339,0.888,4.64,0.475,6.98c-0.089,0.503-0.23,0.996-

0.381,1.484L32.75,442.628z">
    <animate attributeName="fill" begin="mouseover" from="#FF0000" to="#000000" dur="5s"/>
</path>
</svg>
```

Comment: How do i edit admin_svg/BB_birds_in_flight.svg manually at run time so that it will look like dynamically changing color.

Comment: Can you provide me any demo or fiddle link.

Comment: http://www.bittbox.com/wp-content/uploads/vectors/BB_birds_in_flight.svg.zip   here is link for BB_birds svg file

Comment: nice one , but all this work for an internal svg, i need to do this to any external svg files because i have to set different svg file as per users choice

Comment: That's not possible for the reasons I give in my answer.

Comment: is there any other way to change the fill color of svg file which is store in my directory so that i can again set a new modified svg image to background whenever color change event occurs ?

Comment: You could have multiple background images and switch between them. You might need a rather large number of images though.

Comment: whatever , but i need to change external file fill color any how !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37663/discussion-between-sanjay-nakate-and-robert-longson)